# how to parse xml in java using Google Geocode

Tags: java, xml, google-maps

The code

```
try{
       URL url = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Riyadh&sensor=false");
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
       String line;
        while(null != (line = reader.readLine())){
            System.out.println(line);
         }    

    }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
               }
```

The output:

```
Server is Ready....

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <GeocodeResponse>
     <status>OK</status>
     <result>
      <type>locality</type>
      <type>political</type>
      <formatted_address>Riyadh Saudi Arabia</formatted_address>
      <address_component>
       <long_name>Riyadh</long_name>
       <short_name>Riyadh</short_name>
       <type>locality</type>
       <type>political</type>
      </address_component>
      <address_component>
       <long_name>Riyadh Province</long_name>
       <short_name>Riyadh Province</short_name>
       <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
       <type>political</type>
      </address_component>
      <address_component>
       <long_name>Saudi Arabia</long_name>
       <short_name>SA</short_name>
       <type>country</type>
       <type>political</type>
      </address_component>
      <geometry>
       <location>
        <lat>24.7135517</lat>
        <lng>46.6752957</lng>
       </location>
       <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
       <viewport>
        <southwest>
         <lat>24.2939113</lat>
         <lng>46.2981033</lng>
        </southwest>
        <northeast>
         <lat>25.1564724</lat>
         <lng>47.3469543</lng>
        </northeast>
       </viewport>
       <bounds>
        <southwest>
         <lat>24.2939113</lat>
         <lng>46.2981033</lng>
        </southwest>
        <northeast>
         <lat>25.1564724</lat>
         <lng>47.3469543</lng>
        </northeast>
       </bounds>
      </geometry>
      <place_id>ChIJmZNIDYkDLz4R1Z_nmBxNl7o</place_id>
     </result>
    </GeocodeResponse>
```

I'm trying to use Google geocode API to get the coordinates of a city, but I'm facing problem that how can i parse the XML response to retrieve the longitude and the latitude of the city enclosed within the (`<location></location>`) section.

Answer (score 0):

Check the org.w3c.dom.* java library for xml parsing, or JDOM... if you want to access something in a hierarchical way.

Please check [XML Parsers in JAVA](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/index.htm) for more alternatives.

After implementing the code, you just kinda call for the element "location", and iterate through its children and retrieve the values you want.

here's an example:

```
String xmlRecords = "<data><employee><name>A</name>"
    + "<title>Manager</title></employee></data>";

DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));

Document doc = db.parse(is);
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

  NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("name");
  Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
  System.out.println("Name: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

  NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
  line = (Element) title.item(0);
  System.out.println("Title: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
}

}
String xmlRecords = "<data><employee><name>A</name>"
    + "<title>Manager</title></employee></data>";

DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));

Document doc = db.parse(is);
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

  NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("name");
  Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
  System.out.println("Name: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

  NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
  line = (Element) title.item(0);
  System.out.println("Title: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
}

}
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
Node child = e.getFirstChild();
if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
  CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
  return cd.getData();
}
return "";
}
}
```